# CABasicAnimation - switch from one animation to another. How to get currentValue of animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

Hi I'm using CABasicAnimation to animate path in CAShapeLayer. When user tapp the button I called:

```
CABasicAnimation *expandAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    expandAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)].CGPath;
    expandAnimation.duration = 1.0;
    expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    expandAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [self.circleShape addAnimation:expandAnimation forKey:expandAnimation.keyPath];
```

And when releases the button I animate it like this:

```
 CABasicAnimation *narrowAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    narrowAnimation.fromValue = (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)].CGPath;
    narrowAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)].CGPath;
    narrowAnimation.duration = .5;
    narrowAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    narrowAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [self.circleShape addAnimation:narrowAnimation forKey:narrowAnimation.keyPath];
```

Sometimes the first animation is still animating while I start the second one. How on earth can I get the current state of the first animation, so I can set the start value for second animation to begin from that state?

For values Im using BezierPaths.

Comment: Did you try to `[layer removeAnimationForKey:@"path"];` before do the next animation?

Comment: This is not the issue I think. When I call the second animation, the first one stops at that moment automatically. I just want that the circle begins shrinking from the current state not from the maximum size.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `presentationLayer` which returns a copy of the presentation layer object that represents the state of the layer as it currently appears onscreen.

So by using `self.circleShape.presentationLayer` you will get the layer which is currently displayed on the screen.

**EDIT:**
so the solution is

```
narrowAnimation.fromValue = [self.circleShape.presentationLayer valueForKeyPath:@"path"];
```

Comment: I think this it the way to go. But how can I access path property?

Comment: hm.. you can get it's position and start the second animation from that possition

Comment: the CAShapeLayer has a `path` property, isn't that what you need?

Comment: Amazing this was the right way indeed. I'll post the answer.

Comment: Or just add this code to your answer and I can pick your answer as the right one.

Comment: narrowAnimation.fromValue = [self.circleShape.presentationLayer valueForKeyPath:@"path"];